# Controlling chromecast from a Dialogflow chatbot?

Tags: chromecast, dialogflow-es

Currently, you can control your chromecast screen with the Google Assistant by e.g. asking Google Home "OK Google, show a video about food from youtube on living room screen".
But can you do the same inside a selv-created Dialogflow (api.ai) chatbot (e.g. "Cook"), i.e. asking the Google Home: "OK Google, Talk to "Cook" ... show video no. 7 on Living Room Screen"?
What JSON-webhooks to use? APIs? Work-arounds? ... or do I have to wait for Google's "Visual Responses" (now 8 months after their announcements at the 2017 Google I/O conference):
- https://discuss.api.ai/t/api-ai-integration-to-articulate-storyline-2-elearning-to-use-multimedia/5616/2
- http://blog.mirabeau.nl/nl/articles/enriching_a_digital_assistant_conversation_via_your_tv/3DjiL90lRmuGKyeQwq2c0s

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there's no way to control Chromecast through Dialogflow or a Google Assistant Action.